# Sorting Multi-Index levels based on column properties

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a MultiIndex dataframe `df`:

```
                   C         D  E
A    B                           
bar  one    0.934232  0.518263  0
     three  0.079759  0.192417  2
flux six    1.484391 -0.607172  2
     three -1.816136 -0.660524  1
foo  five  -0.695819 -0.406685  0
     one   -0.589729 -0.974765  1
     two    0.640990  0.319567  0
     two    0.485979 -2.127268  1
```

I would like to sort the first level, `A`, based on column-level properties of each value of the level, i.e.:

- The last value of `E`, descending
- The lowest value of `D`, ascending

How can I do that?

The final `df` should keep the first level "contiguous" (i.e. all items in `A` should still be under a single `A`, and the same for `B`, etc.).

In case it helps, here is the  code to generate the random df like the one above:

```
from numpy.random import randn as randn
from numpy.random import randint as randint

def create_random_multi_index():
  df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                            'foo', 'flux', 'foo', 'flux'],  
                     'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                            'two', 'six', 'five', 'three'],
                     'C' : randn(8), 'D' : randn(8), 'E': randint(0,3, size=(8,))})
  df.set_index(['A', 'B'], inplace=True)
  df.sort_index(inplace=True)
  return df


df = create_random_multi_index()
```

### Update:

I tried:

```
e0 = df.groupby(level=0, as_index=False).E.max().E
d0 = df.groupby(level=0, as_index=False).D.last().D
new = df.iloc[pd.concat([e0, d0], 1).sort(['E', 'D'], ascending=[True, False]).index]
```

but I get:

```
                   C         D  E
A    B                           
flux six    1.484391 -0.607172  2
bar  one    0.934232  0.518263  0
     three  0.079759  0.192417  2

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

which isn't right (it's missing a whole first-level entry).

Answer (score 2):

One efficient hack is to replace the levels (of the MultiIndex) inplace, sort, then put them back:

```
In [11]: levels = df.index.levels

In [12]: e0 = -df.groupby(level=0).E.median()

In [13]: d1 = df.groupby(level=1).D.min()

In [14]: df.index.levels = [e0, d1]

In [15]: df = df.sort_index()

In [16]: df.index.levels = levels
```

*This only works because you have an aggregation for each column.*

A potentially more robust way anyway is to get to [transform](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation), use [sort passing a list to ascending](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html):

```
In [21]: e0 = df.groupby(level=0, as_index=False).transform("median").E

In [22]: d0 = df.groupby(level=0, as_index=False).transform("min").D

In [23]: to_sort = pd.concat([e0, d0], 1).reset_index(drop=True)

In [24]: to_sort
Out[24]: 
   E         D
0  2  0.278293
1  2 -0.548683
2  2  0.723572
3  0 -0.160737
4  1  1.174394
5  0 -0.304647
6  0 -0.916528
7  1 -0.350992

In [25]: to_sort.sort(['E', 'D'], ascending=[True, False])
Out[25]: 
   E         D
3  0 -0.160737
5  0 -0.304647
6  0 -0.916528
4  1  1.174394
7  1 -0.350992
2  2  0.723572
0  2  0.278293
1  2 -0.548683
```

and use this result to reindex:

```
In [26]: df.iloc[to_sort.sort(['E', 'D'], ascending=[True, False]).index]
Out[26]:
                   C         D  E
A    B                           
flux three  0.479158 -0.160737  0
foo  one    0.598025 -0.304647  0
     two    0.073532 -0.916528  0
     five   0.866019  1.174394  1
     two    1.259768 -0.350992  1
flux six    2.380352  0.723572  2
bar  one   -0.443605  0.278293  2
     three  0.506341 -0.548683  2
```

Comment: Thanks, although I think `[13]` should be on `level = 0` (note that I am not asking to sort the entries of `level=1`. All the sorting is at `level='A'`. Am I wrong?

Comment: I like however, that this allows me to sort differently depending on the level!

Comment: @user815423426 If you do [13] on level=1, this won't work (it works precisely because it's a different metric on each level). If you have to do two on level=0 then your going to have to do a little more work (something like: `df.groupby(level=0, as_index=False).agg({'D': 'min', 'E': 'median'}).sort(['D', 'E']).index`)

Comment: Also, if one of the columns has dates, and I still want to sort based on it in descending order, I can't use the trick in `[12]` (i.e. using the sign `-`), since I get: `TypeError: ufunc 'negative' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<M8[ns]') dtype('<M8[ns]')`

Comment: @user815423426 ok, I guess you're going to have to do something like above, and pass in ascending list.

Comment: Thanks! Also I think in your comment with `agg` you shouldn't use single quotes around the function names `min` and `median`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @user815423426 actually using quotes is a trick to use the pandas version of min / median rather than defined elsewhere. You can do both (I think pandas does some trickery to use it's version of min rather than python's built-in!) but better to use the quotes :)

Comment: Hi Andy - Thanks again for this very informative answer. Unfortunately (I may be missing something) it doesn't look like this is working. Note that I also replaced `median()` by `last()` to make the sorting clearer, but I also lose entries with `median()`. Maybe I am missing something, see my update to the OP.

Comment: @user815423426 ah cripes, my second answer is totally wrong (I should be using transform).